# How can I do permutations?

Tags: c++, permutation

I'm implementing a game in which a player can ask for a suggestion and the computer should return the word with the highest score.
To do it I should start from a word and from it I should add letters (1 to 7) in order to create a new word that exists.

**Example:**

- Word: the
- Letters: y, m, s, i, r, e, s
- Possible new words: them, they, their, there, thesis, therms, etc.

The idea is to find all the possible permutations and then check for each word if it's in the dictionary. I have already implemented the dictionary and I know how to check words, but I don't know how to find the anagrams.
The fact is that I have to check all the possible word and they may be of different sizes and some of them don't include all the letters.

Comment: Here's an algorithm that does permutations. There's even some pseudocode that will help you implement it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm

Comment: @Blaze I know about the algorithm but I don't think that it would be really helpful in this case

Comment: Why don't you think it would be helpful?

Comment: @Blaze Because I have to check the words of different size. For example I need to check all the words only adding to 'the', the letter 'y', then only adding 'm', ecc. After all the words composed by 4 letters I should pass to all the words of size 5, etc

Comment: What have you done so far? What have you tried? Show your non-working code and we help you fix it.

Comment: How is done your dictionary ? ala scrabble one (by sorted letters to give correct permutation -> `"ehty"` -> `"they"`) then you can jump directly to the potential permutation and check sub-strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need all permutations of the letters of all possible sizes. You can permute the letters and loop through the size and preappend the word.

E. g.

Word: the

Letters: y, m, s, i, r, e, a

- first permutation y, m, s, i, r, e, a

  - size 1 => they,
  - size 2 => theym
  - ...
- second permutation m, y, s, i, r, e, a

  - size 1 => them
  - size 2 => themy
  - ...

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string word{"the"};
    std::string letters{"ymsirea"};
    std::sort(letters.begin(), letters.end());
    do {
        for (std::size_t i(1); i <= letters.length(); ++i) {
            std::cout << word << letters.substr(0, i) << std::endl;
        }
    } while (std::next_permutation(letters.begin(), letters.end()));

    return 0;
}
```

Another solution is to add a special symbol to the letters like `\n` and permute the letters. Then you compare the new word until the special symbol

Word: the

Letters: y, m, s, i, r, e, a, \0

- first permutation y, \0, m, s, i, r, e, a => they
- second permutation y, m, \0, s, i, r, e, a => theym

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string word{"the"};
    std::string letters{"ymsirea\n"};
    std::sort(letters.begin(), letters.end());
    do {
        std::size_t pos = letters.find('\n');
        if (pos > 0)
            std::cout << word << letters.substr(0, pos) << std::endl;
    } while (std::next_permutation(letters.begin(), letters.end()));

    return 0;
}
```

Both algorithms will generate many duplicates. Both algorithms will generate up to (n)!*n words where n is the number of letters. In this example it will produce 7*6*5*4*3*2*7 = 35280 words. If you have duplicates in the letters, std::next_permutation will skip some permutations. You can use a set to filter the duplicates. There can only be a maximum of 7+7*6+7*6*5+7*6*5*4+7*6*5*4*3+7*6*5*4*3*2 = 8659 different words if all letters are unique. So this algorithms produce up to 35280-8659=26621 duplicates.

For the permutation you can use [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Comment: That's exaclty what I tried to do, I had the same idea, but the problem is the implementation

Comment: @AlessiaLuoni What problem do you have?

Comment: The first code doesn't work because it continues to loop and it shows always the same words. The words that it forms are always: 'they', 'theym', theyms', 'theymsi', 'theymsir',  'theymsire',  'theymsires'

Comment: @AlessiaLuoni Here the first code works https://tio.run/##hU/JboMwEL3zFSN6sZVF6TWQ/kpEYAojGRuNhyYt4tupWUKpeuhcbL152@RNc8hNZstheCGbm7ZASMl5Yczqt@gHCwjZcot8YC6Ot0hmSsckVRBGZAXqjKzS0EUQxktxPs8ucHdcdLFUGPfJn6VBEWTfxZ@1J0b/m@NY1MI43rAcA/ZPyRFtobSe6YVbgsd5dwxqNqAvvAqQetUJEKSXVWzQllKpAO92pDfiNTx3rUCaTvXH96n07S10V6c9BF3AJ3LoYpLVo59@PdwrMrhUsfiQa4Nct5IJOfvfXeGwyYVRWrZwSqJ@GL4B

Comment: @AlessiaLuoni thee, theei, theeim, theeimr, theeimrs, theeimrss, theeimrssy, thee, theei, theeim, theeimr, theeimrs, theeimrsy, theeimrsys, ...

Comment: @AlessiaLuoni As I said both codes produce many duplicates but both code also produce all permutations. You can use a set to filter the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the in built algorithm?

This page even has an example that you can use.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Simply loop through all the permutations, preappend 'the' and look it up in your dictionary.

Comment: Because I need word of different size. I mean: I must check 'the+y',  'the+m',  'the+s',  'the+i',  'the+r',  'the+e',  'the+s' and then adding a letters, so,  'the+ym',  'the+ys',  'the+yi',  'the+yr',  'the+ye',  'the+ys' and so on

Comment: A cheap way of doing that would be to loop and drop a letter for each loop. Downside would be testing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Finding anagrams is simple, for each word associate a key that is the same word with its letter sorted. For instance: `orange -> aegnor`. Then create a dictionary whose key is the previously defined key, and whose value is the list of word having this key.

Now, for each letter you add to the input word, sort the word to produce the key, and find all anagrams in this dictionary associated to this new key.

For instance the dictionary would contain:

```
dict["aegnor"] -> [ "orange", "organe" ]
```

Example:

```
input: "the"

First pass:
Key = "eht"
dict["eht"] -> [ "the" ]

Second pass, we add the letter 'm':
Key = "ehmt"
dict["ehmt"] -> [ "meth", "them" ]

...
```

Comment: downvoters: care to explain why ? the OP explicitly stated that is problem is: `I don't know how to find the anagrams`. And computing permutations is **not** the solution as complexity will grow as factorial of `n` and even for an 8 letters input word, this would make the total number of operations more than a thousand of billions (taking into account the 7 letters the OP want to insert).